# Can I copy code licensed under Apache 2 to a project licensed under MIT?

Tags: license-compatibility, mit, apache-2.0

I found a useful class in a project that is licensed under Apache 2.0. Can I copy it to a project licensed under MIT license? Add the library as dependency is not an option.

Ideally the answer should quote the corresponding paragraph of the  license (MIT and/or Apache 2.0) that describe this case.

Comment: Also related, but broader: [Combining code written under different licenses (Eiffel Forum License, MIT and Apache), what are my options?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/combining-code-written-under-different-licenses-eiffel-forum-license-mit-and-a)

Comment: @TimMalone IMHO it is not a duplicate cause i want to add to a MIT licensed project

Comment: From the possible dupe: "licenced under Apache v2 and I want to use MIT..." and "If you copy AL-licensed source code verbatim, you should keep that license on that source code." Isn't that what you want to do..?

Comment: Yes you are right, thats what i want to do. So I can copy the specific class, keep the license header of Apache v2 and the rest of the code base can remain MIT?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Comment: @TimMalone agreed! This is not a duplicate!

Comment: @Chriss what does " So I can copy the specific class, keep the license header of Apache v2 and the rest of the code base can remain MIT?" mean? Like do I need to create new files? (e.g. a `notice.md` file) I am confused what changing the header means or what files I need to explicitly change...

Comment: related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73848/what-type-of-notices-and-licenses-do-i-need-to-add-when-adding-and-modifying-c